# Is there a max number of entries per table for SQLiteDatabase Content Provider

Tags: sql, android

I have an Android app that has a Content Provider with an SQLiteDatabase implementation. I have 1 db that has 3 tables. I noticed that my tables don't get any new row inserted after i reach index number 1000.

This limit is unique for each table. So if i have table_a, table_b, table_c, then if table_a row entries max out at 1000, then table_b and _c can still add more entries, but then table_a does not add any more entries from now on.

I ran this on 2 different phones and noticed that they both can't add new entries after 1000. Is this a limitation that is documented somewhere or is there something wrong with my code?

I read something about setMaximumSize() in the SQLiteDatabase class, but I don't think that would solve my problem because it is related to the number of entries rather then the db file size.

Any thoughts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How is your table schema defined?

Comment: Looks something like this:

CREATE TABLE cell_data (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, col1 TEXT, col2 TEXT, col3 TEXT, col4 TEXT, col5 TEXT, col6 TEXT, col7 TEXT, col8 TEXT, col9 TEXT, col10 TEXT, col11 INT);

(i just changed the column names to preserve ip, which shouldn't be a problem)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the bug in my code. closing so it doesn't stay hanging.

Just to be clear, there is no cap in the number of rows for a table.